# Logo problem that looks bad by the App Store but looks good on me

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm not seen any shortage in the App Store review team for some reason, the application logo is not sized. The App Store gave me a screenshot like this, but it doesn't have such a nuisance in both the simulator and my tadajne device. The logo they send appears in the screen image not sizing.

The codes of the logo in the relevant section are as follows;

First I draw the image,

```
const TextImg = require('../../assets/img/TextImg.png');
```

Then I give you the width and height,

```
       <Image source={TextImg}
style={{ width: width*0.3,height:height*0.04, marginLeft:20 }}
resizeMode={'center'}
/>
```

App store officials sent me the screen image as follows;

[image]

[enter link description here](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/4/8/af02aae73433a9581d5798b43dcd6056-full.png)

It looks neat in all the devices and simulators I tested. However, in the screenshot from the App Store, the logo appears un sized.

Can you help me?

Comment: did answer helps? do u resolve this issue? just curios

Answer (score 0):

This is bacause your image tooks more space that the view.

Try change `resizeMode : 'contain'` 
for more details , please check : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#resizemode